# How can I avoid duplication of jBox2D physics attributes?

Tags: java, architecture, jbox2d

I'm using *jBox2D* for physics and collision detection in a game engine with an entity-component system. It works, but I'm unsure how to structure my code with respect to the values represented in the Physics World and in my Pixel world.

Initially, I had these vectors on my `Entity` class:

```
public Vector position;
public Vector acceleration;
public Vector velocity;

public Body body; //this is jBox2D's physics body object.
```

[Duplication is bad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). How can I reduce the duplication of entity values in jBox2d's physics body?

Comment: and the what???

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit tired. I updated the question.